# How can I use the C++ regex library to find a match and *then* replace it?

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, tokenize

I am writing what amounts to a tiny DSL in which each script is read from a single string, like this:

```
"func1;func2;func1;4*func3;func1"
```

I need to expand the loops, so that the expanded script is:

```
"func1;func2;func1;func3;func3;func3;func3;func1"
```

I have used the C++ standard regex library with the following regex to find those loops:

```cpp
regex  REGEX_SIMPLE_LOOP(":?[0-9]+)\\*([_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*;");
smatch match;
bool   found = std::regex_search(*this, match, std::regex(REGEX_SIMPLE_LOOP));
```

Now, it's not too difficult to read out the loop multiplier and print the function *N* times, but how do I then replace the original match with this string? I want to do this:

```cpp
if (found) match[0].replace(new_string);
```

But I don't see that the library can do this.

My backup place is to `regex_search`, then construct the new string, and then use `regex_replace`, but it seems clunky and inefficient and not nice to essentially do two full searches like that. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1171/ ... isnt this much simpler handeled with `std::string`s methods? `find` and `replace`

Comment: *Is there a cleaner way?*  Write a parser.  Could use Boost [Spirit X3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html), which is designed to be useful for small grammars all the way to complex grammars.

Comment: Can function names start with a number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also NOT use regex, the parsing isn't too difficult.
So regex might be overkill. Demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/RXLqLtrUQ-
(and yes my output gives an extra ; at the end)

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream is{ "func1;func2;func1;4*func3;func1" };
    std::string split;

    // use getline to split
    while (std::getline(is, split, ';'))
    {
        // assume 1 repeat
        std::size_t count = 1;

        // if split part starts with a digit 
        if (std::isdigit(split.front()))
        {
            // look for a *
            auto pos = split.find('*');
            
            // the first part of the string contains the repeat count
            auto count_str = split.substr(0, pos);

            // convert that to a value
            count = std::stoi(count_str);

            // and keep the rest ("funcn")
            split = split.substr(pos + 1, split.size() - pos - 1);
        }

        // now use the repeat count to build the output string
        for (std::size_t n = 0; n < count; ++n)
        {
            std::cout << split << ";";
        }
    }

    // TODO invalid input string handling.

    return 0;
}
```